# SharePoint Server 2013 Prerequisites installer on Win Server 2012 R2

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, windows-server, prerequisites, vmware

I'm trying to install the Prerequisites by running the `prerequisiteinstaller.exe` but i'm stuck at this `Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role: configuration error`

I have tried the following:

1. Do windows update (done with about 60 somthing MB)
2. Adding the roles manually through `Server Manager` but it turns out that they already been added!
3. Failed with installing `KB 2771431`, got this msg `The update is not applicable to your computer.`
4. Tried to do the alternative method `Method 2` as mentioned [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2765260/en-us) and also nothing happened

I'm running this test environment on `VMWare` with 8 G.B of RAM and 120 G.B Hard drive capacity

Please suggest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 is not supported on Windows Server 2012 R2. This will possibly change with the release of SP1 for SharePoint 2013 this spring.

More:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2891274

Comment: Wow, Didn't know that! thanks anyway, Could you please add a reference for your answer.

Comment: Sure can, have added a link to Microsofts open support page regarding this

Answer (score 16):

go to windows\system32 directory.

Then make a backup of servermanager.exe and then rename to servermanagercmd.exe

i hope it will work then!

It works.. for me - Amardeep

Comment: This works for me too...

Comment: This solution works for me too

Comment: You made my day.

Comment: Imran, thank-you so much.

Answer (score 0):

## Making Prerequisites Run

*Apologies in advance for the length of this post, but I think this is fairly important to have in one place.*

Personally, I believe this whole process is a complete minefield.  It has taken me over a week to get this running.

To make sure we are on the same page, I have been attempting to install SharePoint 2013 Foundation (SP1) onto Microsoft Server 2012 R2.

To aid the process, I have installed all of the necessary roles and features manually, in a belt and braces way, by including every single option beneath the standard choice selection.

## Roles and Features...

To clarify, I have installed the following roles and features...

- **.NET Environment 3.5 (Feature)**

  - Windows Process Activation Service
  - .NET Environment 3.5
- **.NET Extensibility 3.5 (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Application Development
  - .NET Extensibility 3.5
- **.NET Extensibility 4.5 (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Application Development
  - .NET Extensibility 4.5
- **.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 3.5 Features
  - .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
- **.NET Framework 3.5 Features (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 3.5 Features
- **.NET Framework 4.5 (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 4.5 Features
  - .NET Framework 4.5
- **.NET Framework 4.5 (Role Service)**

  - Application Server
  - .NET Framework 4.5
- **.NET Framework 4.5 Features (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 4.5 Features
- **Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (Role)**

  - Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services
- **Active Directory module for Windows PowerShell (Feature)**

  - Remote Server Administration Tools
  - Role Administration Tools
  - AD DS and AD LDS Tools
  - Active Directory module for Windows PowerShell
- **AD DS and AD LDS Tools (Feature)**

  - Remote Server Administration Tools
  - Role Administration Tools
  - AD DS and AD LDS Tools
- **AD LDS Snap-Ins and Command-Line Tools (Feature)**

  - Remote Server Administration Tools
  - Role Administration Tools
  - AD DS and AD LDS Tools
  - AD LDS Snap-Ins and Command-Line Tools
- **Application Development (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Application Development
- **Application Initialization (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Application Development
  - Application Initialization
- **Application Server (Role)**

  - Application Server
- **ASP (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Application Development
  - ASP
- **ASP.NET 3.5 (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Application Development
  - ASP.NET 3.5
- **ASP.NET 4.5 (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 4.5 Features
  - ASP.NET 4.5
- **ASP.NET 4.5 (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Application Development
  - ASP.NET 4.5
- **Basic Authentication (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Security
  - Basic Authentication
- **Centralized SSL Certificate Support (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Security
  - Centralized SSL Certificate Support
- **CGI (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Application Development
  - CGI
- **Client Certificate Mapping Authentication (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Security
  - Client Certificate Mapping Authentication
- **COM+ Network Access (Role Service)**

  - Application Server
  - COM+ Network Access
- **Common HTTP Features (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Common HTTP Features
- **Configuration APIs (Feature)**

  - Windows Process Activation Service
  - Configuration APIs
- **Custom Logging (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Health and Diagnostics
  - Custom Logging
- **Default Document (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Common HTTP Features
  - Default Document
- **Digest Authentication (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Security
  - Digest Authentication
- **Directory Browsing (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Common HTTP Features
  - Directory Browsing
- **Distributed Transactions (Role Service)**

  - Application Server
  - Distributed Transactions
- **Dynamic Content Compression (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Performance
  - Dynamic Content Compression
- **Health and Diagnostics (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Health and Diagnostics
- **HTTP Activation (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 3.5 Features
  - HTTP Activation
- **HTTP Activation (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 4.5 Features
  - WCF Services
  - HTTP Activation
- **HTTP Activation (Role Service)**

  - Application Server
  - Windows Process Activation Service Support
  - HTTP Activation
- **HTTP Errors (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Common HTTP Features
  - HTTP Errors
- **HTTP Logging (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Health and Diagnostics
  - HTTP Logging
- **HTTP Redirection (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Common HTTP Features
  - HTTP Redirection
- **IIS 6 Management Compatibility (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Management Tools
  - IIS 6 Management Compatibility
- **IIS 6 Management Console (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Management Tools
  - IIS 6 Management Compatibility
  - IIS 6 Management Console
- **IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Management Tools
  - IIS 6 Management Compatibility
  - IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility
- **IIS 6 Scripting Tools (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Management Tools
  - IIS 6 Management Compatibility
  - IIS 6 Scripting Tools
- **IIS 6 WMI Compatibility (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Management Tools
  - IIS 6 Management Compatibility
  - IIS 6 WMI Compatibility
- **IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Security
  - IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication
- **IIS Hostable Web Core (Feature)**

  - IIS Hostable Web Core
- **IIS Management Console (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Management Tools
  - IIS Management Console
- **IIS Management Scripts and Tools (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Management Tools
  - IIS Management Scripts and Tools
- **IP and Domain Restrictions (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Security
  - IP and Domain Restrictions
- **ISAPI Extensions (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Application Development
  - ISAPI Extensions
- **ISAPI Filters (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Application Development
  - ISAPI Filters
- **Logging Tools (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Health and Diagnostics
  - Logging Tools
- **Management OData IIS Extension (Feature)**

  - Management OData IIS Extension
- **Management Service (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Management Tools
  - Management Service
- **Management Tools (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Management Tools
- **Message Queuing (MSMQ) Activation (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 4.5 Features
  - WCF Services
  - Message Queuing (MSMQ) Activation
- **Named Pipe Activation (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 4.5 Features
  - WCF Services
  - Named Pipe Activation
- **Named Pipes Activation (Role Service)**

  - Application Server
  - Windows Process Activation Service Support
  - Named Pipes Activation
- **Non-HTTP Activation (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 3.5 Features
  - Non-HTTP Activation
- **ODBC Logging (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Health and Diagnostics
  - ODBC Logging
- **Performance (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Performance
- **Request Filtering (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Security
  - Request Filtering
- **Request Monitor (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Health and Diagnostics
  - Request Monitor
- **Role Administration Tools (Feature)**

  - Remote Server Administration Tools
  - Role Administration Tools
- **Security (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Security
- **Server Side Includes (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Application Development
  - Server Side Includes
- **Static Content (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Common HTTP Features
  - Static Content
- **Static Content Compression (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Performance
  - Static Content Compression
- **TCP Activation (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 4.5 Features
  - WCF Services
  - TCP Activation
- **TCP Activation (Role Service)**

  - Application Server
  - Windows Process Activation Service Support
  - TCP Activation
- **TCP Port Sharing (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 4.5 Features
  - WCF Services
  - TCP Port Sharing
- **TCP Port Sharing (Role Service)**

  - Application Server
  - TCP Port Sharing
- **Tracing (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Health and Diagnostics
  - Tracing
- **URL Authorization (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Security
  - URL Authorization
- **WCF Services (Feature)**

  - .NET Framework 4.5 Features
  - WCF Services
- **Web Server (IIS) (Role)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
- **Web Server (IIS) Support (Role Service)**

  - Application Server
  - Web Server (IIS) Support
- **Web Server (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
- **WebDAV Publishing (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Common HTTP Features
  - WebDAV Publishing
- **WebSocket Protocol (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Application Development
  - WebSocket Protocol
- **Windows Authentication (Role Service)**

  - Web Server (IIS)
  - Web Server
  - Security
  - Windows Authentication
- **Windows Identity Foundation 3.5 (Feature)**

  - Windows Identity Foundation 3.5
- **Windows PowerShell 4.0 (Feature)**

  - Windows PowerShell
  - Windows PowerShell 4.0
- **Windows Process Activation Service Support (Role Service)**

  - Application Server
  - Windows Process Activation Service Support
- **WS-Atomic Transactions (Role Service)**

  - Application Server
  - Distributed Transactions
  - WS-Atomic Transactions

## Anthony Marsiglia

The two most important pieces of information, however, can be attributed to Anthony Marsiglia, from his blog posts on this matter...

- [SharePoint Foundations 2013 Offline Part 1 (Download all Prerequisite software)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/connector_space/2015/10/02/sharepoint-foundations-2013-offline-part-1-download-all-prerequisite-software/)
- [SharePoint Foundations 2013 Offline Part 2 (Install Prerequisites)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/connector_space/2015/10/03/sharepoint-foundations-2013-offline-part-2-install-prerequisites/)

I found the second part less useful, however, except for the execution order of each of the prerequisite files.  Don't bother extracting the data from the **sharepoint.exe** file - it becomes unnecessary due to another problem.

## Server 2012 R2

Some things have changed with 2012 R2 versus its predecessors, the primary one (in our case) being the way in which Server Manager has changed its name from **servermanagercmd.exe** to **servermanager.exe**.

Another invaluable tip was learned right here on this thread from [@ImranJalali](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/101528/82211), above:

> go to windows\system32 directory.
>
> Then make a backup of servermanager.exe and then rename to servermanagercmd.exe
>
> i hope it will work then!
>
> It works.. for me - Amardeep

The logfile from the prereq. installer hints at the problem, but without actually looking into the **System32** folder (or, in my case, I'm simply not a server admin, more of a developer), it's difficult to understand why the line fails...

> 2019-07-16 15:35:19 - "C:\Windows\system32\ServerManagerCmd.exe" -inputpath "C:\Users\pweston\AppData\Local\Temp\Pre6DB8.tmp.XML"
>
> 2019-07-16 15:35:19 - Error: Unable to install (2)
>
> 2019-07-16 15:35:19 - Error: [In HRESULT format] (-2147024894)

This was the final piece of the jigsaw for me, to get the SharePoint prerequisites to actually do their job.  Once all of the previous steps were complete the program reconfigured all of the necessary services and completed without error.

## Coming in Season 2...

I have yet to install SharePoint itself, however, but will update this post when I have done so.