# Error on configuring AppFabric on Windows server 2012.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, installation

I'm tyring to configure AppFabric on Windows svr 2012 r2. 
I  installed it my machine but when I try to run sharepoint 2013 prerequisites installer, it returns me a error. 
[image]

Comment: We have had at least two other questions regarding SharePoint 2013 and Windows Server 2012 R2. It is not supported to install SP 2013 on 2012 R2 until SharePoint 2013 SP1 is released!

Comment: See: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85883/sharepoint-server-2013-prerequisites-installer-on-win-server-2012-r2/85886#85886 . Your question is not a duplicate so it will remain open for now, but your answer is in that post

Answer (score 1):

AppFabric comes with the SharePoint prerequisites installer. Did you try to install it manually before running this setup? Try to uninstall it and re-run the prereqs installer.

> Note: Appfabric installation and configuration has to be done by the
>   prerequisite installer ONLY and not in a stand-alone manner.

You can implement any one of the two solutions listed below:

> Solution 1:    Append the following path to PSModulePath entry in the environment variables - %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
>
> ◦Go to My Computer, right-click Properties
>
> ◦On the System' page,
>   click Advanced System Settings on the left-side pane.
>
> ◦If you receive
>   a UAC prompt, click on Yes to launch the System Properties dialog box
>
> ◦From the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables
>
> ◦Within the
>   System Variables section in the lower half, select PSModulePath and
>   click on Edit (or double-click PSModulePath')
>
> ◦Append the following
>   path to PSModulePath entry in the environment variables
>
> `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`
>
> ◦Ensure that the
>   PSModulePath entry looks like this:
>
> `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;c:\Program
>   Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\PowershellModules`
>
> Solution 2
>
> ◦There are chances that other applications might be referencing the
>   same variable and may fail if it is deleted. This is what we can do if
>   solution 1 does not help.
>
> ◦Remove the PSModulePath entry from the
>   'Environment Variables' and re-run the installer. Once it completes
>   successfully, ensure that the PSModulePath entry looks the same as
>   mentioned in solution 1.

Source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2013/02/22/sharepoint-2013-prerequisites-fails-with-msi-installer-error-code-1603-while-installing-appfabric-1-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 will not support Windows Server 2012 R2 until SharePoint 2013 with Service Pack 1 is released.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved] Kindly, follow the mentioned steps in this article to configure windows server AppFabric correctly
https://mohamedelkassas.wordpress.com/2014/06/14/windows-server-appfabric-is-not-correctly-configured-as-sharepoint-2013-prerequisites/

Comment: Quote the main aspects of the article as links tend to go down.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91919/what-to-do-with-error-message-windows-server-appfabric-is-not-correctly-configu/171119#171119). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!